# Growth Rates by custom time period in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rate, slicers

I have sales data for TV category for 24 months with columns like

```
DATE    Region    Brand   SKU     SALES     
Jan19    North   SAMSUNG  138358  1000  
Feb19    North     LG     118074  100
Jan20    South     TCL    142740  2000  
Feb20    West    SAMSUNG  144591  150
Dec20    West    SAMSUNG  111111  200
```

I am setting up 2 slicers/filters for the "DATE" columns - "BASE DATE" and "CURRENT DATE". In the backend, there are two pivots, one for each base date and current date.  However, I am not able to calculate the custom period growth rate. For example, if the user filters BASE DATE as Jan 19 and CURRENT DATE as Dec 20, I should be able to calculate the growth rate like [(Dec20-Jan19)/(Jan19)]*100.

Is there any way to do it? Even using a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

[image: Result picture]

In C12 there is a formula `=(E9-B9)/B9` or you can also have `=E9/B9-1` with 'Percentage' as a cell format.